# Java Multithreading Array Separating

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I need to separate an array considering count of threads. For example i have the array *[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10]* and user print count of thread which will be work with elements in this array. My task is distribute the work between arrays' elements and threads.

Count of threads = 2 -> *thread1:[1][2][3][4][5] thread2:[6][7][8][9][10]*.
But what i need to do if threads will be for instance 7. Ho to separate work in this case?

Comment: `[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10]` is a *10-dimensional array*, not a single array of 10 elements. `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` is a single array with 10 elements.

Comment: How about using an ExecutorService with a Threadpool that have the required number of threads? Like ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize). Then, you can submit the tasks by iterating though the array and submitting each element as a parameter to a runnable task. Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is sample application which splits input array to threads:

```
final int threadCount = 7;
final int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

int from = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
    final int to = (from + (int) Math.ceil((a.length - from) / (double) (threadCount - i)));
    System.out.println("Thread #" + i + " will use " + Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, from, to)));

    from = to;
}
```

actually (thanks to @Andreas), instead of ceiling, you can use simply integer math:

```
final int to = from + ((a.length - from) / (threadCount - i));
```

output:

```
Thread #0 will use [1, 2]
Thread #1 will use [3, 4]
Thread #2 will use [5, 6]
Thread #3 will use [7]
Thread #4 will use [8]
Thread #5 will use [9]
Thread #6 will use [10]
```

Comment: I like `Math.round()` better. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas math.round will not work, for example 11 elements and 10 threads

Comment: It works. Try it. You can even do `Math.floor()`. Why should the first threads get all the fun?

Comment: @Andreas oh, you're right, you can do floor or round

Comment: You can see the difference between `ceil()`, `round()`, and `floor()` in [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/tHNlhs).

Comment: @Andreas yep, I've already figured out that all variants will work, I like floor better, because it can use only integer math